# Does anyone have any references relating to supermarkets pricing goods to keep CPI down?

Tags: reference-request, inflation

On BBC Radio 4's Today programme during the Business News on the 31st August 22, I heard an ex-buyer for a major UK supermarket saying that they always kept a list of CPI goods and they made sure that these didn't go up in price.

I wanted to use this as a reference, however I was unable to make an audio recording because the recording is only available on the BBC Sounds app is available for 30 days (I missed it by one day).

The interviewee basically said, for inflation to be this high in supermarkets then cost pressure must be enormous because the CPI goods were always the last ones they put up. Thus implying other goods cross subsidised the CPI goods.

Could anyone give me some references on this either academic or in popular media. At the moment this has now become a half remembered annecdote to tell my mates in the pub.

Comment: I take it that's a no then!